# Show all text in a title of a form

Tags: c#, winforms, size, width, titlebar

My text title may be of different length, and I want that text fully fit within the entire title bar of a form. So I need to change width of a form. But how to know a width of a text in a title, when in different systems font and size of title text can be very different?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089280/adapt-the-size-of-a-form-to-its-title-text-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2):

May be this could help,

```
    private void YourFormName_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = 300; // the default or initial width
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

           if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                this.Width = 300;
                goto END;
            }
            if (textBox1.Text.Length < this.Width)
                this.Width = textBox1.Text.Length;
            else
                this.Width = this.Width + textBox1.Text.Length;
        END:this.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In WPF that is resolved easy, but as for **Windows Forms**, I think you may inherit from standard `Window` control and in the initialization code assign header title width (it must be simple to calculate, as Andrei V mentioned in comments) to a form.

Answer (score 0):

In the form, Put the following code in the constructor:

```
this.Width = this.Width + this.Text.Length;
```

`this.text` returns the text of the title. `this.width` returns the width of the form. Just adjust the width according to the length of the text in the title.