# Is it possible to get the width of a form's text in the titlebar?

Tags: c#, winforms

A simple question, just as stated in the title...  How can I get the width of the title on a form?

I want to resize a form to match the width of text in the title bar.

[image]

Comment: You could try using [MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx), passing the text and `SystemFonts.CaptionFont`.

Comment: Have you ever seen a window with such behavior? I believe it's possible, but not a good idea. Anyway, here is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18089280/3110834).

Comment: Please be aware that `MeasureString` is a "fuzzy" calculation - it's not accurate and there's no way to adjust for the inaccuracy.

Comment: Yea @RezaAghaei a messagebox (I'm not only checking the titlebar, that's just the one I didn't know how to measure).  ;)  And that was EXACTLY what I needed, I looked around for a similar question but could not find one.  Thanks for pointing it out guys!

Comment: I feel @Enigmativity needs some credit for flagging the dup pointing me to the other question as well so +1 from me on that comment too.  ;)